# How can I use TypeKit fonts in wireframing?

Tags: adobe, typography, typekit

I've long used TypeKit for front-end development, but is there a way to access TypeKit fonts on desktop Adobe applications (Ps, Ai) without downloading them privately (expensively!) from a foundry?

Answer (score 0):

Too Easy, Just download and install free google fonts since 2010.  http://www.google.com/fonts
I just embed tho through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked several months ago, but for other people's benefit: some Typekit fonts can now be synced to desktop.